# SQL Server set decimal separator different than OS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, separator, culture

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server Standard 14.0.1000.169 in a machine whose culture (from Powershell Get-Culture) is `it-IT` hence the decimal separator is the comma.

I am unable to load data containing numbers with the decimal dot separator in columns set as "decimal" or "float" as the server only accepts commas.

How can I configure the database to use a different culture than the system's?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.3.1

Comment: Interesting question (although it would surprise me that it hasn't been asked before on SO).  But powershell also has [Set-Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture)

Comment: @LukStorms it looks like everybody just performs a replace on the data, but I don't want to change the data. I don't want to change the locale of the whole server machine either as it could break something else. I just need to change the delimitator of one specific database